# Pagination with condition from form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-pagination

I want to make pagination with condition from form in laravel. but when I click page 2, there's nothing in there. the sketch is like this

[pagination page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EiJt.png)

[pagination page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTeJW.png)

my code in controller is like this

```
 public function search(Request $request){

    if($request->emotion=="all"){
        $data = Dataset::select('*')->where([
            ['category', '=', $request->category]    
        ])->paginate(15);
    }
    else{
        $data = Dataset::select('*')->where([
            ['category', '=', $request->category],
            ['label', '=', $request->emotion]    
        ])->paginate(15);
    }

    return view('dataset.search', [
        'data' => $data,
        'label' => $request->emotion
    ]);
}
```

and in route is like this

```
Route::post('/dataset-detail', [DatasetController::class, 'search']);
Route::get('/dataset-detail', [DatasetController::class, 'search']);
```

and in view like this

```
<tbody>
                                @if($data==NULL)
                                <td colspan="8">NO DATA FOUND IN HERE !</td>
                                @else
                                    @foreach ($data as $datas)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $datas->tweet }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $datas->text_processing }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $datas->akurasi_naive }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $datas->akurasi_svm }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ $datas->akurasi_knn }}</td>
                                        <td><a class="btn btn-primary">{{ $datas->label }}</a></td>
                                        @if($datas->category=="train_test")
                                            <td>Training and Testing</td>
                                        @else
                                            <td>Validation</td>
                                        @endif
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ $data->links() }}</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

how to make the paginate works with condition that I input before in form like in function search ?

Comment: you can simplify your code like $data = Dataset::query()->where(function ($query)use($request){

            $query->where('category', '=', $request->category);
            if($request->emotion!="all"){
                $query->where('emotion', '=', $request->emotion);
            }
        })->paginate(15)->withQueryString(); this instead of duplicates

Comment: From your route definitions, I suspect you are POSTing filters, so when you click on the second page, which is a GET request, your posted data will not be there.  Ideally, oftentimes, search forms are GET requests. I would say that using GET on your filter form along with `withQueryString` function on `paginate` would fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

add to your code with this :

```
->paginate(15)->withQueryString();
```